# Smart Group that returns those recently added

Tags: smartgroups

I'm attempting to create a smart group that returns a list of people added on the current date without having to edit the criteria each day.

I've been starting with the "Date Added to CiviCRM" custom search, entering a date, then editing the civicrm_saved_search entry with no luck. Alternately, I'd settle for something that returns the last few people added using the maximum contact id number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, you should be able to use **Search menu > Advanced Search**, select the "Change Log" accordion, and select the "Added" radio button.  Then you can use relative date filters.  I just tried it and it worked OK.  I seem to recall that in Civi 4.3 and lower this was slow or broken, but should work in any modern version of Civi.

Comment: Perfect. I totally missed this because I limited my search options. For those who don't see "Change Log" in their advanced search, go to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences. Look for "Contact Search" and check "Change Log".

Answer (score 2):

You could copy the 'Date Added to CiviCRM' custom search and edit it. Had a quick go here and it seemed to work if you change $startDate and $endDate to just be the current day. So altering the block at line 181:

```
$startDate = date('Y-m-d');
$endDateFix = NULL;
if (!empty($this->_formValues['end_date'])) {
  $endDate = date('Y-m-d');
  # tack 11:59pm on to make search inclusive of the end date
  $endDateFix = "AND date_added <= '" . substr($endDate, 0, 10) . " 23:59:00'";
}
```

Not terribly elegant, but I think that works. You'd probably want to remove the date fields from the form too, just to avoid confusion.